# UINT64 is not a member of boost

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, boost

I'm running into some issues compiling one of our programs using boost 1_62_0 under VS2012.  I've previously had this compiling under VS2015 I believe (however can't verify this).

I turned on `/showIncludes` to get an idea of where exactly its having the problem, and I've narrowed it down to inclusion of `typeindex` from the VS2012 includes:

```
Note: including file:          C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~3.0\VC\include\crtdefs.h^M
Note: including file:        \\COMPILESERVER\BASENT\dev\lib\src\third_party\boost\boost_latest_win64_vs2012\boost/limits.hpp^M
Note: including file:       \\COMPILESERVER\BASENT\dev\lib\src\third_party\boost\boost_latest_win64_vs2012\boost/limits.hpp^M
Note: including file:       \\COMPILESERVER\BASENT\dev\lib\src\third_party\boost\boost_latest_win64_vs2012\boost/type_traits/is_enum.hpp^M
Note: including file:       \\COMPILESERVER\BASENT\dev\lib\src\third_party\boost\boost_latest_win64_vs2012\boost/type_traits/is_integral.hpp^M
Note: including file:       \\COMPILESERVER\BASENT\dev\lib\src\third_party\boost\boost_latest_win64_vs2012\boost/utility/enable_if.hpp^M
Note: including file:       \\COMPILESERVER\BASENT\dev\lib\src\third_party\boost\boost_latest_win64_vs2012\boost/cstdint.hpp^M
Note: including file:       C:\PROGRA~2\MICROS~3.0\VC\include\typeindex^M
\\COMPILESERVER\BASENT\dev\lib\src\third_party\boost\boost_latest_win64_vs2012\boost/functional/hash/hash.hpp(236) : error C2039: 'UINT64' : is not a member of 'boost'^M
\\COMPILESERVER\BASENT\dev\lib\src\third_party\boost\boost_latest_win64_vs2012\boost/functional/hash/hash.hpp(237) : error C2039: 'UINT64' : is not a member of 'boost'^M
Note: including file:       \\COMPILESERVER\BASENT\dev\lib\src\third_party\boost\boost_latest_win64_vs2012\boost/functional/hash/extensions.hpp^M
```

Using #pragma message, I can verify that it has `using ::uint64_t` within the boost namespace in cstdint.hpp

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: `::uint64_t` specifically refers to the *global* namespace, not the boost one - that's what `::` means.

Comment: Smells like a macro rat.  But the first thing you need to do is find a 4 year old Boost version.  Expecting that 1.62 can work on such an old compiler is far too optimistic.  Aim for ~1.53

Comment: @HansPassant I'd fix the issue at hand first. I'm pretty positive Boost doesn't use or declare `UINT64`. Also, 1.62.0 still lists (partial) VC8 (VS2005) support

Comment: Jesper I was just implying that ::uint64_t was being defined (using...) within the boost namespace so boost::uint64_t should work just fine.  It looks like it is a macro in our code somewhere that has triggered this.  Sometimes it just needs someone else to push you in the right direction!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed this smells like a MACRO.

You should find out which header defines something like

```
#define uint64_t UINT64
```

You can save the preprocessor output of the failing translation unit to find this.